# Boolean difference not works! model object linked

Tags: boolean-modifier

<strike>I have two objects to make hole.
Left one is the object what I want to subtract as you see , boolen make nothing happened</strike>

Right one is the mesh cylinder for just boolen test and it works.

What am I missing in my mesh?
"Inertersect" , "Union" all works but only "Difference" not working.

It's reproduced. here is link for your better understanding
https://cloud.wise-leader.com/index.php/s/jfYy1bshAECtjq8

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have flipped normals on the object you want to substract. In this example, both cylinder objects should be subtracted from the plane, but the left one isn't:

[image: boolean not working]

If you enable *Face Orientation* in the *Overlays*, you can see see faces of the left cylinder are showing red, meaning their inside is pointing outwards, while all the other faces are blue:

[image: face orientation]

To change this, select the cylinder and <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*, select all faces with <kbd>A</kbd>, then hit either <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Normals* to turn them all blue or if some of them stay red, select those and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Normals* > *Flip* to make blue as well.

[image: flip normals]

[image: all faces blue]

You can now disable *Face Orientation* again, and as you can see on the plane back in *Object Mode*, both *Boolean* modifiers are now working:

[image: boolean working]

Comment: Thanks Brinkmann!
Actually, it's not my case. But it's also good answer for such an occasion.
My case is mesh is unstable with manifold state due to hole design and boolen modifier difference effect is somehow not working.
This is happening for me since I am not experieced person for 3D modeling but just beginner with many hole drawing :) Anyway, Thanks for your professional answer !

Comment: If it's not your case, then we need more information on your objects or maybe you nbeed to upload your file... and you don't have to accept answers that don't solve your problem - because others might have the same and it would be a bit disappointing if this is marked as accepted but it doesn't help. As an optional answer it will stay here as long as I don't delete it ;)

Comment: Problem reproduced and modleing data linked now !

Comment: Gordon's answer is correct, I opened the example file you uploaded and turned on Face Orientation in the Overlays and the Cylinder is red, and the rectangular prism is blue. Selecting the cylinder and going to Edit Mode, selecting all the faces and pressing Shift+N to recalculate the normals resolves the issue. It's named Circle.003 so I suspect what happened was you extruded a circle, which by default when you extrude it up, its normals will face inward.